# Is it possible to make endnotes in MS Word not follow a specific numbering?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have made some endnotes in MS Word at the end of the section in my document. Is there a way to make the numbers be whatever numbers I want instead of following a list like 1, 2, 3, etc.? I am referencing some text in a previous document I made where I have citations. Here is the text.

> ...as discussed by Lentink and Dickinson<sup>3,11</sup>, Jardin and David<sup>16,17</sup>.

I would like to make the superscripts 3, 11, 16, and 17 the numbers for my endnotes at the bottom of this section in the document.

If this isn't possible, what are my other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Microsoft Word won't allow it.

As far as I see, you have two options:

1. Manually do what you want. The 3, 11, 16 and 17 you write them as powers and in the bottom of the page you draw a line, then the explanations for these references;
2. You use a program which is made for reference management. The first that comes to mind is Endnote.